# Prove $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x^3}{|x|} = +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

We want to prove $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^3}{|x|} = \infty$. I don't think the usual "$\varepsilon-\delta$ definition would work since we are dealing with $\infty$. How else could I approach this problem?

I know plugging in $\infty$ would show this. But is there a more rigorous proof?

For example, if I wanted to change this problem so that $x\to0$ the plugging-in method would not work anymore since we cannot divide by $0$. So there must be a way to solve this so that this problem does not arise!

Thank you.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "the usual".  The definition of$$f(x)\to\infty\quad\hbox{as}\quad x\to\infty$$is$$\forall M\in{\Bbb R}\ \exists X\in{\Bbb R}\ \forall x\in{\Bbb R}((x>X)\Rightarrow(f(x)>M))\ .$$

Comment: Well you can't say any value "=" $\infty$.  I'm not sure what the right notation is to use because I have long argued that divergent limits are quite a bit different than simply indeterminate limits (e.g. oscillating limits).

Comment: So how do you deal with the case when we are finding $lim_{x\to \infty} x$? This clearly grows infinitely large, so if we cannot say this $lim=\infty$, what do we say?

Comment: BTW the "[$\epsilon$-$\delta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit)" definition doesn't work because this limit doesn't exist (which can be showed by using an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof).

Comment: This is true! Thank you. That's the perfect way to articulate what I was thinking :P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For positive $x$, $|x|=x$, so

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^3}{|x|}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^3}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x^2=\infty$$

Comment: Thank you! You've answered another one of my questions before too, haha.

Comment: @DavidSouth of course :)

Comment: What would you do in the case where we are taking the limit as $x \to -\infty$? We have negative $x$ in this case. Can we still use the logic from your answer?

Comment: Just note that for negative $x$, $|x|=-x$ and the answer will be $-\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x > 0$, $|x| = x$. Since we're taking $x$ to infinity, $x$ must pass $0$ at some point, so we can claim

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{x^3}{|x|} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x^3}{x}.$$

From here you can make two arguments: either we discount the removable singularity at $x=0$, because we're onwards to $+\infty$ anyways, or we can use L'Hopital. In either case, we'll get something that is proportional to $\lim_{x\to+\infty} x^2$.

Comment: Thank you! How about in the situation where $x\to-\infty$? What would we do with the absolute value in that situation then?

Comment: Well, what is $|x|$ when $x < 0$?

Answer (score 0):

An application of L'Hopital's rule can be used here, since we have something of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. This gives
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x^2}{|x|'}
\end{equation*}
where $'$ denotes the derivative with respect to $x$. Since the denominator has a horizontal asymptote at $1$, we have 
\begin{equation*}
3\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2=\infty.
\end{equation*}